# Installing Build Tools from Android Studio

Tags: macos, android-studio

I have a problem with Android Studio on OSX. The following error message is shown

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.2
>   **Install Build Tools 23.0.2 and sync project**

[image]

The link, unfortunately, isn't clickable. It should be, I know it works on Windows, but OSX, it's not responding.

SDK Manager on OSX is a little different. It doesn't allow you to install older versions of Build Tools (only the latest).

[image]

So the question is "How can I install 23.0.2 Build Tools on OSX?"

or maybe "Why is my Android Studio install buggy and I can't click any links! :)"

Comment: The latest should be good enough. The thing asking you to install 23.0.2 means "something at 23.0.2 or later", to my knowledge.

Comment: Hmmm ... interesting. Well I have 25.1.3 according to SDK manager but if I go into android\sdk\build-tools I see version 23.0.3. Yet still Android Studio won't do a gradle sync

Comment: Android Studio is an inconsistent piece of... (sorry, I'm used to Xcode, Visual Studio and PHPStorm, all of which are excellent IDEs)

Comment: ^^ Visual Studio :) Same. I think I have a solution though, and it's a bit noobish ...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. I know it's a bit noobish but I went into build.gradle and changed the buildToolsVersion from 23.0.2 to 23.0.3 (which I know is installed)

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.3'
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    minifyEnabled = false
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
    documentationFolder = "${rootDir}/outputDoc/"
}
```

Comment: I must stress this works perfectly on Windows - just click the link to upgrade build tools. On OSX I've seen it work on one machine but not on another. Not sure the difference in configuration ...